# What part of a TV is on during standby mode that makes the small noise inside the box?

Tags: components

I'm intrigued by the old debate about stand by mode vs switching off for longevity.

It would appear that stand by mode wins out, but there is still electricity <strike>generated</strike> consumed so something must be active.

Why does this not lead to wear and tear compared to letting all components rest by switching the device off?

Comment: Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, as they differ from typical forums. (b) Your question *title* asks which part of a TV is on during standby, but the question *text* seems to ask about the difference in reliability between "standby" and "off". [Edit: Removed advice to make title & text consistent, since the question has received an answer in its current state. Edits that would invalidate an answer are discouraged.] (c) Questions about consumer electronics are [off-topic](/help/on-topic) so don't be surprised if this question gets closed.

Comment: (d) Comments here quickly became a discussion and (at least partial) answers, neither of which is an [allowed use of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued *there*. [Go to this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152224/discussion-on-question-by-ryo-what-part-of-a-tv-is-on-during-stand-by-mode-that). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. *Keep it in chat now, please!*

Comment: (e) Any improvement / clarification to the question decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit], not as a comment. When someone has enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. Although, as noted above, questions about consumer electronics are off-topic. So unless an on-topic angle is found, this question may be closed. TY

Comment: Summary: **Discussion in comments has been moved to chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152224/discussion-on-question-by-ryo-what-part-of-a-tv-is-on-during-stand-by-mode-that) and should be continued at that link.** Further comments posted here may be deleted without notice.

Answer (score 3):

> What part of a tv is on during stand by mode that makes the small noise inside the box?

The noise is (almost certainly) coming from the switching power supply in the TV. Specifically, it is likely an inductor (or transformer) that is making the noise, in which case it is called coil whine. Some capacitors can also make audible noise.

> Why does this not lead to wear and tear compared to letting all components rest by switching the device off?

The difference between wear and tear while on standby vs being completely unpowered is small. However, while on standby, "smoothing" capacitors in the power supply remain charged, but with very little ripple current. This can help preserve the capacitors. In fact, if they remain uncharged for a long period of time, their lifespan will be shortened. This does happen with other devices (not powered on standby) which for one reason or another remain unused for several years. They do not work properly when restarted, although they worked fine the before they fell into disuse.

Comment: In standby, only a small portion of the device is powered. For example a desktop PC has a standby supply and main supply, so only 5VSB is available in standby and main supply is off, so output caps are not charged. Different devices may work differently and a TV might compare with a PC in sleep mode with all supplies on.

Answer (score 1):

> What part of a tv is on during stand by mode that makes the small
> noise inside the box?

The noise is coming from magnetic core of power supply transformer, from usual [magnetostriction](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/materials-science/electrostriction) effect. All ferrites emit acoustic noise when subjected to change in magnetic field, which is the main mode of transformer operation.

All [modern AC-DC converters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/705724/117785) (power supplies) use switching method, they convert low-frequency mains AC into DC, then "chops" this DC into high-frequency AC, transform the pulses into lower voltage AC with a transformer, and rectify the pulses into DC suitable for modern digital electronics. Voltage regulation usually comes from modulation of pulse width and/or frequency.

The power converter usually operates at high frequency under normal operational load, so humans don't hear the sound. However, when the appliance is turned into standby mode and consumes very little power, the power supply must reduce pulses to almost nothing, and even skip bunches of them to remain in closed controlled loop. And the mode of inductor current may change as well. As result, some cheap supplies produce nearly random pulses in standby mode, and a part of core-emitted sound spectrum enters the human-sensitive range. That's where you starts hearing the "hissing noise".

The "longevity" is a very different topic, it depends on overall quality of design of the converter.